# In highchart how to plot the line in 3d container

Tags: highcharts

Please any one help me. How to plot the line chart in 3d Highcharts. They provide the example chart for 3D column chart but i want 3d line chart. How to plot the line chart instead of Column chart.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: there are many ways to achieve this. shows us what you've tried or explored yourself..

Comment: new Highcharts.Chart({ chart: {renderTo: 'container',type: 'column'}); instead of type 'column' i am using 'line'. Plot is successfully generated but while rotate the chart only container is rotated not the chart. In case of type='column' both container and chart are rotated..

Comment: Unfortunately only scatter/pie/column series are supported in 3D mode.

Answer (score 2):

Plotting lines is just line plotting points, originally shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/3d-scatter-draggable/)

To change that plot from points to lines, first change the `colorByPoint` to false. Then add `lineWidth: 1`. That will get you lines. To remove the vertex markers, add to `plotOptions.scatter`:

```
marker: {
    enabled: false // true removes vertex markers
}
```

Finished example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ebrewste/pweu5cm5/)